# Indefinite integral of an odd, continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This is my first question in stackexchange:
Suppose we have an odd, continuous function f defined on entire Real line. Now, I integrate f from -infinity to +infinity. Under which condition/conditions on f, the resultant integral will be 0?

Answer (score 1):

A necessary and sufficient condition is that the integral exists. There are a handful of definitions of $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx$. The condition of its existence will change what this entails depending on the definition.

For example:

- In the case of improper Riemann integral we have that it is equivalent to $\lim_{t\to+\infty}\int_{0}^{t}f(x)dx$ must exist.
- In the case of Lebesgue integral it is equivalent to $\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx$ being finite.
- In the case of Cauchy's principal value it is equivalent to no other condition, the value will always be zero.